# Multiply adjacency list by -1

Tags: python, list, adjacency-list

```
g = [
    [4, 7],
    [3],
    [4, 5],
    [4],
    [2],
    [0]
]
```

I´m trying to multiply the adjacency list above using this piece of code:

```
for i in range(len(g)):
    for j in g[i]:
        g[i] = [j * (-1) for j in g[i]]
        

print(g)
```

the result i´m getting is:

```
[[4, 7], [-3], [4, 5], [-4], [-2], [0]]
```

what do i have to chage so all the list would be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multiply every element in sublist by `-1`:

```py
g = [[4, 7], [3], [4, 5], [4], [2], [0]]

g_neg = [[v * -1 for v in subl] for subl in g]
print(g_neg)
```

Prints:

```
[[-4, -7], [-3], [-4, -5], [-4], [-2], [0]]
```